# ServiceStack AuthUserSession Roles & Permissions not populated when UseDistinctRoleTables

Tags: session, authentication, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm not sure whether this is an issue or not, but AuthUserSession Roles an d Permissions properties are not populated when the UseDistinctRoleTables property of OrmLiteAuthRepository is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design as mentioned in the [New IManageRoles API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#new-imanageroles-api) section in the release notes.

The `UseDistinctRoleTables` controls whether the roles are blobbed with the user or stored in distinct `UserAuthRole` table.

Comment: Isn't  the Session supposed to contain the roles and permissions despite the fact where or how that information is persisted? The behavior isn't consistent / if you let UseDistinctRoleTables to false you get roles/permissions out of the session object while you don't get that info if it is set to true.

Comment: @gjspaho It's just implemented differently, use the `Session.HasRole()` and `Session.HasPermission()` API's to check for roles and permissions. If the `IAuthRepository` supports `IManageRoles` then it will use that instead. When using `OrmLiteAuthRepository`, it always checks the database to ensure the user has a role.

Comment: well in my scenario I was sending the user session to the JavaScript client, including roles. When I switched to UseDistinctRoleTables the roles didn't get populated. I'm adding some extra code to send that info now. Thanks for the clarification.